# Find process with most TCP sockets?

Tags: debian, bash

How can I find the process with the most TCP sockets that is currently running with bash ?

I would like to only output the process name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you interested in TCP sockets only then lsof +c 0 -i tcp is an answer, otherwise you need extend options for lsof to include other types of sockets

```
ps -ef | pgrep -lf `lsof +c 0 -i tcp | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'` | cut -d' ' -f2 | uniq | sed -e 's/^.*\///'
```

Andrey

Answer (score 1):

```
# ps -p $(netstat -tnp|awk '$6=="ESTABLISHED" {split($7,a,"/"); print a[1]}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}') -o comm=
skype
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm getting on raspbian (No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
error: process ID list syntax error

Comment: As it says in the error message, you should run that as root. For future reference, if you see '#' in the command you are meant to use, that's an indication to run it as root.